# Copy content from <div> into a form field every time it changes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

What i need to do is copy the content of a div with id #logo to a form field with id #input_2_15.

The content in the div is an image (`<img src.../>`), but this changes... I have the code to copy the content to the input field when the page loads, but i need a code which copies the content every time the image changes (and it does so without refreshing the page). How can i do this?

Also, is it possible to get the function to only copy the image name eg. 12345.png rather than the whole `<img src=..../>`?

Miro

Comment: What causes the image to change? If it is a AJAX request, put the code to copy the contents in the success handler of the AJAX.

Comment: Then place the logic in the success handler

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#logo').find('img').attr('src');
```

This will give you the image location.. now just append this to your img src in the second div

Comment: I thought you had to place it somewhere..that is why i talking about the second div .. the above code will fetch u the path of the image.. now as you need the image name you can just split it .. i mean try something like this :
var imagePath = $('#logo').find('img').attr('src');
var imageName = imagePath.split("/");
console.log(imageName[imageName.length-1]);

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
function getUrl(id) {
  // function to return the source of an image inside an object with given ID
  return $("#"+id).find("img").attr("src");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentImage = getUrl("logo"); // get the url of the div now (empty I guess)

  $("#ajaxtrigger").click(function() { // some link with ID ajaxtrigger

    $("#logo").load("someurlreturningsomehmtl",function(){ // loads the image
      if (currentImage != getUrl("logo")) { // did it change?
        currentImage = getUrl("logo"); // save the name
        $("#input_2_15").val(currentImage); // update the field
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Im not sure exactly whats going on here, im sorry...
The image in the div changed when the user uploads a new image. I would like the file name of the image to copy to a text field. If it's easier, can we get it to copy the file name when i hover over a button?

Comment: I added some comments. You need to change ajaxtrigger and someurlreturningsomehtml to whatever your code has

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a case for a "publish and subscribe" ("Pub/Sub") approach.

In [this article](https://gist.github.com/1321768), we learn four ways to do Pub/Sub with jQuery 1.7, and I chose Option 1 which exploits a new feature of jquery 1.7, namely its $.Callbacks feature. The article gives a good understanding, which I will not try to better here.

The code below is a slightly modified version of Option 1, avoiding need for a global var:

```
$.Topic = function(id) {
    var callbacks, topic = id && $.Topic.topics[id];
    if (!topic) {
        callbacks = $.Callbacks();
        topic = {
            publish: callbacks.fire,
            subscribe: callbacks.add,
            unsubscribe: callbacks.remove
        };
        if (id) {
            $.Topic.topics[id] = topic;
        }
    }
    return topic;
};
$.Topic.topics = {};//avoid global var by making `topics` a property of the static function `jQuery.Topic`.

$(function() {

     //A function to change the logo and fire a publisher. 
    function changeLogoSrc(src) {
        $("#logo img").attr('src', src);
        $.Topic('logoSrcChanged').publish(src); 
    }

    // A subscriber which listenes for the 'logoSrcChanged' publisher 
    // and responds by writing the src string to the required form field
    $.Topic('logoSrcChanged').subscribe(function(src) {
        $("#input_2_15").val(src);
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jCaQ3/3/)

Thus the code for changing the logo and for updating the form field are, to use the correct jargon, effectively "decoupled".

This approach is arguably overblown for something simple, but would be useful in a more extensive environment where many pub/subs are required.